# Is it possible to remote debug unit tests on the build server using Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, teamcity

When unit tests are failing on the build server but not locally on my computer I would like to debug the code to find the problem. The build server runs Team City.

Comment: You can't debug the unit tests that TeamCity is running, but you should be able to spawn a process on the same server and debug that. I wouldn't advise it though. Is there no other option in finding out why the test fails?

Comment: There are other options, e.g. printing a lot of information that gives clues about why it fails. But it is tedious and time consuming.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution I used:

1. Within your test c#/vb code file, create a log file that would trace whatever you want to trace/print from the test you would debug. One possible location of that log file could be: ***%system.teamcity.build.checkoutDir%\LOG.TXT***

2. After the test build step, create a PowerShell script that will copy the trace/log file onto a shared folder, that could be a shared folder on your machine (do not forget to give write/modify permissions to the build server user account on the share and folder security). If you don't know the builder user account, grant write/modify permissions to Everyone on that share (alert: this is unsafe from a security standpoint). Here is how that copy command could look like:
***copy -Force %system.teamcity.build.checkoutDir%\LOG.TXT \MyMachineName\LogUnitTestsShare***